# Symfony Sonata Admin - How to add multiple fileds on the same entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have the following problem. I have two tables cars and equipment. Some equipment is required and some are not. Now I try to add two fields to the Sonata Admin FormFields, but I don't know how to add two fields with a query on the same entity.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('MyBundle\Entity\Equipment');

    $queryEquipment = $em->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->from('MyBundle:Equipment', 'a')
        ->where('a.required = 1');

    $queryOptionalEquipment = $em->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->from('MyBundle:Equipment', 'a')
        ->where('a.required = 0');

    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('equipments','sonata_type_model', array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'label' => 'Equipment',
            'query' => $queryEquipment,
        ))
        ->add('equipments','sonata_type_model', array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'label' => 'Equipment optional',
            'query' => $queryOptionalEquipment,
        ))
    ;
}
```

This will only show the last field in the form. Anyone know how to archive this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to create a virtual property (e.g. `optionalEquiments`) with accessors that add/remove equipments from the real `equipements` property. To fill your form fields correctly, you'll need to set the `class` and `property_path`  options of the virtual field and your queries should do the job of displaying the good values in corresponding fields.